# Pass byte array into C function from VC++

Tags: visual-c++, windows-phone-8

How do I pass bytes to c function from VC++. I am using WinRT compilation.

Error: Incompatible with parameter type.

C function

```
 int TestFunction(unsigned char testdata[])
 {
 }
```

VC++ class

```
 int Wrapper::DoSomething(IVector<unsigned char>^ inputBytes)
 {
      TestFunction(inputBytes);
 }
```

Comment: That's not XOR it's a managed pointer in C++/CX.

Comment: If I remove that xor the VC++ editor showing a error like "a parameter cannot have a c++/cx mapping interface class type."